# CakePHP : REST API 404 Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rest, cakephp

I have build a REST server and trying to make my java application communicate to it.
But I keep getting a 404 error.

When I type in the url in my browser along with the function name like:

```
[url]/controller/functionname/1.json
```

it works fine, returning me the right data.
Without the function name:

```
[url]/controller/1.json
```

I get this error:

```
"action 1.json not defined in controller".
```

I've checked my `.htaccess` file and routes against a previous version I had build which was working just fine. I can't figure out what the problem might be. Any suggestions?

And oh, I should mention, the earlier version that I talked about was build on windows and this one on ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to cakephp or any .htaccess. If you receive your data with a browser you should be able get with java/curl/whatever.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I receive the data when send along the function name from my browser. Something like url/controller/functionname/1.json. When I do a normal url/controller/1.json, I get an error action 1.json not found.

Comment: I suppose you should update your question then.